# Add Calculated Virtual Column to Django Model Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm having a tough time trying to add a virtual column to my django model.

My `Store` model has the following database fields:

```
from pytz import timezone, all_timezones

TIMEZONES = tuple(zip(all_timezones, all_timezones))

class Store(models.Model):
    time_opening = models.TimeField()
    time_closing = models.TimeField()
    # 'america/los_angeles'
    time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=TIMEZONES)
```

How can I add an `is_open` field to the results of my Store queryset?

The logic for the field is something like:

```
time_opening <= datetime.now(tz=timezone(time_zone)) <= time_closing
```

I have attempted to use annotations in a StoreManager class but I'm not sure how to construct an expression with the logic mentioned above.

```
class StoreManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(is_open=??????)
```

I also wrote the raw sql as a backup which returns a virtual column is_open based on the desired logic. For example:

```
SELECT Store.*, True as is_open;
```

In this case, I'm unsure where to use my raw sql. Do I put it in the StoreManager get_queryset function?
Do I call Store.objects.raw()? If so, where should I call it? How will it affect built-in django filtering and pagination?

Comment: `from django.db.models import BooleanField, Q, ExpressionWrapper; .annotate(is_open=ExpressionWrapper(Q(time_opening__gte=datetime.now().time(), time_closingt__lte=datetime.now().time()),output_field=BooleanField()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your `Store` objects with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q
from django.utils.timezone import now

class StoreManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time = now().time()
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            is_open=ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(time_opening__lte=time, time_closing__gte=time)
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )
```